# Using A UI Picker To Controller 2 Different Labels

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UI issue. Initially I wanted to have 2 pickers to populate 2 different labels. The problem is using 2 pickers on the ui will take up all the space on the window and you cannot resize the pickers.

I realized since I am using the same data in each of the pickers I should be able to get away with using one picker control. Except it will be a little confusing to the user if the focus of the control isnt done properly.

I would like for it to work kinda like the keyboard coming up in a textbox.

So I have a simple UI

Get Data 1:   Textbox1
Get Data 2:   Textbox2

A picker

When the user clicks inside textbox1 a picker appears instead instead of the keyboard and populates the textbox with the selected data off the picker. The same happens for textbox2.

Can someone give me a sample of how this maybe accomplished, or a better way to approach this? How do you guys handle having to have 2 dropdown menus on the same window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A picker with two components and two labels (or textfields) is a good solution if your text isn't too long.

**Edited to add**

Here's a picker with two components that I just whipped together.

[image: UIPickerView with two components]

**Further edited to add**

Here's some code to show you how it's done:

**Set up the components**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}
```

**Set up the rows**

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        return [array1 count];
    } else {
        return [array2 count];
    }
}
```

**Provide data for the rows**

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

**Change the labels based on changes in the picker**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        label1.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        label2.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have 2 different components in one picker? Can you show me a sample of side A populating label 1 and side B populating label 2?

Comment: @Matt-Can you show me the source for that? I didnt know you could do that. Also can you add a third wheel in the middle of the 2 that is just a "-" and that wheel doesnt move so your example the selection line would read Banana-Monkey. An thank you for showing this too me

Comment: @Nick Posted some code. Adding the middle hyphen would require (a) returning 3 for `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`; (b) modifying `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` to return a value from array1 for component 0, `@"-"` for component 1, and a value from array2 for component 2 in `titleForRow`; (c) modifying `didSelectRow` to change the labels based on `component == 0` and `component == 2` values; and (d) implementing the `UIPickerViewDelegate` method `pickerView:widthForComponent:` method to size the components (probably 150, 20, and 150, or so).

Comment: @Nick Apple's class reference shows what the methods look like. Know that you'll need to implement `<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>` in your interface file. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html